# ActionMailer not instantiating correct mailer class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm working on Ruby on Rails 4.0.0 with ActionMailer 4.0.0.  I am unable to send emails despite following the Rails guides, nor am I able to successfully test.  Inspecting the ActionMailer instance from rails console I am observing the NullMailer being instantiated, which (does nothing)TM

```
>> rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
2.0.0p247 :001 > er = EventRegistration.last
2.0.0p247 :003 > MainMailer.event_registration(er)
=> #<ActionMailer::Base::NullMail:0x007fc11cbe3108>
```

I've double-checked everything against the Rails guides and even the comments within the ActionMailer's code base.  Here are my files:

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '= 4.0.0'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '= 4.0.0'

# Use HAML for HTML
gem 'haml-rails'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'el_finder'

gem 'uglifier'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'kaminari', '~> 0.14.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.0.0'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'erb2haml'

  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder'

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.12b5'
gem 'thinking-sphinx'

gem 'pdf-writer', github: "mwlang/pdf-writer"

gem 'pothoven-attachment_fu', github: 'mwlang/attachment_fu'
gem 'prototype-rails'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'dynamic_form'

gem 'formtastic', github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'mwlang/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'ransack', github: 'ernie/ransack', branch: 'rails-4'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'

gem "will_paginate"
gem "whenever"
gem 'vcard'
gem 'icalendar'

gem 'builder'

gem 'rmagick'

gem 'activeadmin-sortable-tree', github: 'nebirhos/activeadmin-sortable-tree'
gem 'acts_as_tree'
gem "html_helpers", github: 'mwlang/html_helpers'

gem 'better_errors', group: :development
gem 'quiet_assets', group: [:development, :test]
gem "guard-rails", group: :development
gem 'guard-rspec', require: false, group: :development
```

In `config/environments/test.rb` I have:

```
# Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
# The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
# ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

My `EventRegistration` model:

```
class EventRegistration < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :email, :event_id
  validates_format_of :email,
    :with => /\A[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+\z/,
    :message => "was not well-formed"
  belongs_to :event

  def send_notifications
    EventMailer.event_registration(self).deliver
    EventMailer.event_confirmation(self).deliver
  end
end
```

And the spec for `EventRegistration`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe EventRegistration do
  let(:event) { 
    NormalEvent.create({
      "name"=>"Whats up Doc?",
      "type_of_event"=>"Cartoon",
      "presented_by"=>"Looney Tunes",
      "speakers"=>"Donald Duck",
      "duration"=>"30 minutes",
      "status_id"=>"100",
      "allow_registration"=>"1",
      "starts_on(1i)"=>"2015",
      "starts_on(2i)"=>"3",
      "starts_on(3i)"=>"11",
      "start_time"=>"06:35",
      "end_time"=>"07:00",
      "hide_date"=>"0",
      "summary"=>"Not much",
      "details"=>"<p>Cartoon with the wabbit in it.</p>"
    })
  }

  let(:registration) {
    EventRegistration.create({
      "first_name"=>"Bugs",
      "title"=>"Wabbit",
      "address1"=>"123 Nowhere St",
      "city"=>"Anyville",
      "postal_code"=>"12345",
      "email"=>"bugs.bunny@looneytunes.com",
      "last_name"=>"Bunny",
      "company_name"=>"Looney Tunes",
      "state"=>"GA",
      "country"=>"USA",
      "phone"=>"555-555-1234",
      "event_id" => event.id}
    })
  }

  it "should initialize" do
    assert_equal true, event.valid?
    assert_equal true, registration.valid?
  end

  it "should send notifications" do
    registration.send_notifications
    assert !ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?
  end
end
```

The `assert !ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?` line fails

Any ideas why a NullMailer would be instantiated instead of the TestMailer?  For what its worth, the NullMailer is also instantioted for production even though SMTP settings have been configured.

Comment: In RSpec you should be using `expect(event).to be_valid`, and `expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries).to_not be_empty` rather than the `assert_` methods that you are using.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you post your `MainMailer` code also.

Comment: MainMailer was eliminated, but accidentally made its way here by copying and piecing together the gists I was sharing on IRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling [`ActionMailer::Base#mail`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail) in `MainMailer#event_registration`.

Comment: This solved the issue!  Perhaps, like the controller's DoubleRender exception, ActionMailer should be raising an error if one fails to call the #mail method!